# How do I run the code having problems to run methods connected with Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to make people search words when they click the enter key. The words are in the Firebase database. This fragment code acts for listing posts after writing. I want to add the search function, but some methods do not work again. They work just one time (when listing posts). I've been struggling the whole day!

My code does not work at log number 19,14 of `private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText)`, but `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` work first (log number 19,1444 of `private void fetch()`).

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewContainer);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        //rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        fetch();

        write_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_write);
        write_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Post_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
        mSearch = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.mSearch);


        mSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Log.d("aaa", "1"+query);
                String searchText = query;
                Log.d("aaa", "2"+searchText);

                firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
                Log.d("aaa", "3");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
            return view;
    }


    private void fetch() {

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("posts");
        Log.d("aaa", "10" + query);
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Post>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Post parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            return new 
Post(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),

snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString(),

snapshot.child("content").getValue().toString());
                            }
                        })
                        .build();
        Log.d("aaa", "11" + options);

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, ViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                Log.d("aaa", "19");


                return new ViewHolder(view);

            }


            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int 
position, Post post) {
                holder.setTxtTitle(post.getTitle());
                holder.setTxtContent(post.getContent());
                Log.d("aaa", "1444" + holder);
                holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        };


        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.d("aaa", "199");




    }

    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

        Query firebaseSearchQuery = 
mUserDatabase.orderByChild("title").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + 
"\uf8ff");
        Log.d("aaa", "3"+mUserDatabase);
        Log.d("aaa", "3"+firebaseSearchQuery);
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options2 =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                        .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, new 
SnapshotParser<Post>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Post parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot 
 snapshot) {
                                return new 
Post(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),

snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString(),

snapshot.child("content").getValue().toString());
                            }
                        })
                        .build();

        Log.d("aaa", "3"+options2);


        Log.d("aaa", "333");

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, ViewHolder>(options2) {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                Log.d("aaa", "19");


                return new ViewHolder(view);

            }


            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int 
position, Post post) {
                holder.setTxtTitle(post.getTitle());
                holder.setTxtContent(post.getContent());
                Log.d("aaa", "14" + holder);
                holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        };
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I do not know why the methods are not activated again. My goal is to display posts the user finds. Thank you for reading!

Comment: So what is the expected result?

Comment: @AlexMamo i write down the below...my goal is seach function. do you know why 'adapter= ' parts do not work?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved .
so feel blue.
"mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts"); "
i changed this part. and many? things. 
i did digging a lot . the conclusion is that the main problem was my wrong query. 
if the query is wrong the methods linking with firebaserecycleradapter do not work. 
thank you bye